SAPUI5 Filterbar Alignment
I need some help. I'm not able to align the filter fields correctly ... do you have a smart hint for me?
Smartfilterbar
Here is the corresponding coding:
Coding
I tried to play around with the flexBox but got an control error.
Perfect alignment would be all in one line or one above the other.
I'm new to this - so could please be kind to me :-)
Thanks in advance
Sven

What is the result of your research so far? Please avoid adding screenshots of the code but add a minimal sample or a link of it with which readers can easily reproduce the issue. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please note that sap.ui.webc.main.DateRangePicker is deprecated. You might want to use sap.m.DateRangeSelection or sap.m.DynamicDateRange instead.

Remove the class "sapUiMediumMarginBotton" from DateRangePicker. Alignment is missing because of this class added in the XML.

the "sapUiMediumMarginBotton" was the key! Thank you!
I will look at the DateRangeSelection instead of the DateRangerPicker too!
Thank you all for your help!
